# My Command blocks are stuck in a certain mode

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every current command block being placed is stuck in impulse.It is also stuck to being always active, and every command is unconditional. So that means no command will work. This is affecting every world I have.

Comment: So when you try to change it will it just not let you, or does it reset upon exiting the menu?

Comment: It straight up just doesn't let me.

Comment: Try adding screenshots or a short gif of whats happening. It is pretty hard to understand without it as it seems there migth be a misscommunication here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the button that says "Impulse"? Click that button and you should see a drop down where you can change it to Chain or Repeat. You can also do that to the conditional/unconditional.

Comment: I know. I see it, but it is not changing. I change it to repeat, still impulse. set to conditional, still unconditional. Set it to Needs Redstone, it's still always active. I don't know what is going on, but it is affecting every world.

Comment: How did you obtain the command blocks? DId you use commands to get it or did you do Pick Block on an Impulse command block.

Comment: I use commands. No matter which type of command block I get, it's still stuck. The older command blocks work just fine. Just the new ones I get right now don't work.

Comment: When you get a command block for repeating/chain you won't be able to change that. But if you do `/give @p command_block` then you should still be able to change it

Comment: Nope. I always start by impulse.

Comment: Well then thats weird. There's probably something wrong with your game as that should not happen...

Answer (score 0):

A fix is that I do is save and re-enter the map.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two reasons you may not be able to change a command blocks properties:

- You are in survival mode. Fix this by switching to creative.
- Command blocks have been disabled in world settings. Fix this in world settings.